# MATLAB - how to take a string as an argument for a function

Tags: matlab

How can I include the string filename to the fopen function? See code and comments below.

```
for i=1:5
  filename = strcat('Cali',num2str(i)); 
  %first iteration: filename = Cali1          
  %instead of result.txt there should be Cali1.txt in the following statement, but i want to achieve this by using the string filename 

  fid = fopen( 'results.txt', 'wt' );
  fprintf( fid, 'write something');
  fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: This is [clearly stated in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnoom-1). Pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: possibly need to add the file extension too... `filename = strcat('Cali',num2str(i),'.txt'); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic Matlab functionality. You should read the manual a bit more closely. That said, here's the code you need:

```
for i=1:5
  fid = fopen(['Cali' num2str(i) '.txt'], 'wt');
  fprintf(fid, 'write something');
  fclose(fid);
end
```

If you want to use `strcat`, just add the line `filename = strcat('Cali', num2str(i), '.txt');` in the code you had above.